# UI not updating on some devices

Tags: android, user-interface, updates, android-constraintlayout

I have an app which has `SlidingPaneLayout` on the left (hidden by default) and main layout on the visible part of the screen. UI elements, such as `TextView`s, icons (using `vectors`) and `SeekBar` are displayed 
 in this main layout and are updated based on user interactions. Layout is created using `ConstraintLayout`.

```
<com....SlidingPaneLayout
    layout_width="match_parent"
    layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_panel"
        layout_width="200dp"
        layout_height="match_parent">
        ...
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        layout_width="match_parent"
        layout_height="match_parent">
       ...
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_example_icon"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_icon" />
       ...
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</com....SlidingPaneLayout>
```

There's nothing strange in this layout. Components are updating using methods like `setText`, `setImageResource` etc, called from the main thread. The problem is, on some devices (last occurence on Samsung J3, Android 5.1.1), these methods are not working (it works on thousands of other devices). Element is clicked, but content is not updated (e.g. changing icon when user touches the icon). It is updated only after `SlidingPane` is displayed (swiped from the left), or activity is resumed. Does anybody know what can prevent app from updating those elements? It worked well before new update. New update brought: `ConstraintLayout`, png background, `vector` icons.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the problem. Setting fade color from semi-transparent to transparent solved the issue.

```
this.setSliderFadeColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.transparent));
```

However I still do not know reason of this.